# Posting to tumblr using API v2 on iOS returning error

Tags: ios, api, oauth, tumblr

I recently got oAuth working for my iOS app to log in to Tumblr. Now I'm having trouble posting using the new API calls. I'm able to generate a request and prepare Autorization headers but I'm still getting errors.

Here is my URL:

> http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/my_blog.tumblr.com/post?tweet=no&tags=my%2C%20app&state=published&type=text&title=Hello&body=I%2520finally%2520got%2520this%2520to%2520work

Here is my Authorization header with x's in place of sensitive info:

> Authorization = "OAuth realm=\"\", oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_token=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_signature=\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_timestamp=\"1347656207\", oauth_nonce=\"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";

There error I receive:

> {"meta":{"status":400,"msg":"Bad Request"},"response":{"errors":["Post cannot be empty."]}}

Does anyone have experience with this? I've been working at it for at least 20 hours over a two day period.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've also tried including authorization data in the url (i.e., oauth_token, oauth_consumer_key), essentially the stuff found in the header. When I do this I get a 401 "Not Authorized" error, which I know isn't correct because I just successfully called "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info" which requires a valid authorization.

found solution, see explanation [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/107860-using-oauth-with-tumblr.html#latest).

Comment: Any resolution to this? Lots of people having this exact issue but nobody posting a fix.

Comment: @Warblr Did u get any Solution??